# Approximation needed

Tags: special-functions, approximation

I need the approximation for following function $$f(x)=E_1(x)e^{x}$$ where $E_1(x)$ is the exponential integral. I know the following bounds on the above function (they are obtained from Abramovitz book) $$\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\frac{2}{x})<e^{x}E_1(x)<\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would be your question? If you know those bounds, why isn't that sufficient for your needs? What kind of approximation do you need, numerical (which precision?) or asymptotic (which region, real, complex,...)?

Comment: @ProfessorVector i am actually interested in small values of $x$ (smaller than $1$). Can you tell me which of the above bound is more closer to the actual value for $0<x<1$?

Comment: You should write so *in your question*. Judge yourself, the bracketing is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#/media/File:BracketingE1.png) (blue - LHS, red - RHS).

Comment: See also https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.8 for other inequalities.